# MFC application occassionally freezing on exit

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a MFC dialog application that occasionally will freeze on exit. I can set a breakpoint at CWinApp::ExitInstance and it will get there but on continuing will hang.

I don't seem to have the option in Visual Studio to break the program either, only "Stop Debugging".

The only thing special about the app is it does most of its work (file processing) in a separate thread while the UI just shows a progress bar.

It's been a while since I have done any C++ or MFC coding so am a bit rusty how to debug such a problem. So I am looking for some ideas how to debug this or what is most likely the cause?

Memory leak?
Thread deadlock?
Thread not exiting?

Comment: If you can't break/pause execution via Visual Studio dump the process memory and put it into windbg. [!analyze -v -hang](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562112(v=vs.85).aspx) or whatever it is.

Comment: Make sure the worker-thread has been notified and *completely* shuts down (its thread handle is signaled) before exiting the main UI thread.

Comment: Run the application under **Application Verifier.**

Comment: I recommend you to Open the VS Threads window and when execution stops at that breakpoint, Freeze the thread(s) that you think to be the cause of the hanging. I suspect there is a thread doing a never ending operation or application is waiting for termination of a thread that never terminates. My suggestion could help for the first case.